# xcode 4.4.1 x86_64 linker + Intel XE 12.1 bug?

Tags: linker-errors, x86-64, xcode4.4

I have a problematic issue with the linker in xcode 4.4.1 & x86_64 and Intel compiler XE 12.1.

When linking i have this error :

```
0  0x1010cb280  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x1010e7ad4  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86_64>::parse(mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 3444
2  0x1010d43c2  mach_o::relocatable::Parser<x86_64>::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 290
3  0x1010d09db  mach_o::relocatable::parse(unsigned char const*, unsigned long long, char const*, long, ld::File::Ordinal, mach_o::relocatable::ParserOptions const&) + 91
4  0x10110b7b5  ld::tool::InputFiles::makeFile(Options::FileInfo const&, bool) + 565
5  0x10110d217  ld::tool::InputFiles::parseWorkerThread() + 263
6  0x7fff8719d742  _pthread_start + 327
A linker snapshot was created at:
/tmp/TemplatePlugin-2012-10-28-141503.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (cfiStartsArray[i] != cfiStartsArray[i-1]), function parse, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-133.3/src/ld/parsers/macho_relocatable_file.cpp, line 1549.
```

Everything work great with I386 architecture.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: How about the linker provided with Xcode 4.5.2?

Comment: I'm currently downloading it, but there is usually an integration problem between intel compiler and last xcode release. I hope it will fix it.

Comment: You are using the intel compiler?  I think that's an important fact you neglected to mention.

Comment: You'r right, i have edited.

Comment: I have installed XCode 4.5.2, with no success.